# Fourier inversion formula: $\mu(\{a\})=\lim_T \frac1{2T}\int_{-T}^T e^{-ita}\varphi(t)dt$ stuck on closing argument

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'm trying to show that for a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ with characteristic function $\varphi$ we have
$$\mu(\{a\}) = \lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac1{2T}\int_{-T}^Te^{-ita}\varphi(t)dt$$
I got so far, before running into convergence problems:
$$\begin{equation}
I_T = \frac1{2T}\int_{-T}^T e^{-ita}\varphi(t)dt = \frac1{2T}\int_{-T}^T e^{-ita}\left (\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{itx} \mu(dx)\right) dt
\end{equation}$$
So by Fubini:
$$\tag{1}I_T = \frac 1 {2T}\int_\mathbb{R} \mu(dx)\int_{-T}^T e^{it(x-a)}dt$$
We can calculate the inner integral explicitly using symmetry, Eulers formula:
$$\frac1{2T}\int_{-T}^T e^{it(x-a)}dt = \frac{1}{T(x-a)}\sin(T(x-a))$$
Now here I have the issue: When $T\rightarrow\infty$ (we may pull the limit in by dominated convergence), the inner integrand in (1) will vanish everywhere (which is exactly what's needed) unless $x = a$, in which case it is ill-defined (which seems to be a problem).

How can I formally get from here to "$\mu(\{a\})$ is all that's left"?

Comment: I'm not sure if I have interpreted your question correctly but you can extend $\sin(x)/x$ at the point $x=0$, since it is a removable singularity, by its limit value $1$.

Comment: @MarcoCantarini good god how did I forget about that

Comment: You can also observe that he integrand is locally integrable so the result is immediate from the Lebesgue density theorem.